# Adding an element at the head of a linked list, if the element isn't in the list

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I have the following data structure:

```
typedef struct Word {
    char *word;
    int occur;
    struct Word *next_word;
} * WordList;
```

I'm trying to implement a function that adds a string (word) to a `WordList`. If it's already present in the list, then increment its occurrences, otherwise, add it to the head. This function also returns the occurrences of said word in the list.

What follows is my implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int addAtHead(WordList *w, char *word) {
    WordList head = *w;

    while (*w && strcmp((*w)->word, word) != 0)
        w = &(*w)->next_word;

    if (!*w) {
        WordList new = malloc(sizeof(struct Word));

        size_t length = strlen(word) + 1;
        new->word = malloc(length);
        memcpy(new->word, word, length);

        new->occur = 0;

        new->next_word = head;
        *w = new;
    }

    return ++(*w)->occur;
}
```

I have these next functions to test the previous one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printWordList(WordList w) {
    for ( ; w; w = w->next_word)
        printf("Word: %s\nOccurrences: %d\n\n",
            w->word, w->occur);
}

int main(void) {
    WordList w = NULL;

    addAtHead(&w, "world");
    addAtHead(&w, "hello");
    printWordList(w);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run the executable, I get this result:

```
> Word: world Occurrences: 1
> 
> Word: hello Occurrences: 1
> 
> Word: world Occurrences: 1
> 
> Word: hello Occurrences: 1
> 
> Word: world Occurrences: 1
> 
> Word: hello Occurrences: 1
```

and on, and on..

I assumed that somewhere in my code I link the last element to the first, so I drew the following diagrams to figure out where this happens.

[image]

[image]

I then hypothesized that the problem lies in the line `*w = new;`.
How do I go about setting `*w` to start of the list again, without creating a circular list?

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  what is the definition of `WordList`?  Some `#include` statements are needed for `stdio.h`.  This statement: `WordList w = NULL;`  should be: `WordList *w = NULL;`     Please post a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: @user3629249
The following include statements are required to compile the code. I chose not to include them as they were implicit.

`#include <stdio.h>   #include <stdlib.h>   #include <string.h>`.

`WordList` is defined as `typedef struct Word *WordList;`, in the same place where the struct is defined.

Comment: The requirements of stackoverflow for questions about a run time problem, as this question is doing, require a [mcve]  I.E. the inputs, the outputs, code that cleanly compiles, etc.  Please edit the question, and do not put code into your comments

Comment: @user3629249 edited.

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct Word 
{
    char *word;
    int occur;
    struct Word *next_word;
} * WordList;`   Do not hide pointers in `typedef`s.  rather create the pointer when declaring an instance of the typedef.. Also, this: `* WordList;` should be: `WordList *;`

Comment: OT: When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `return ++(*w)->occur;`  this will increment where `W` points rather than the field `occur`.  Suggest: `return ((*w)->occur)++;`

Comment: @user3629249 Actually, the precedence is okay. The problem is in the line `new->nextWord = head;` That creates a circular linked list from the last node back to the head.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code a little bit ... maybe you'll get the idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Word {
  char *word;
  int occur;
  struct Word *next_word;
}WordList;

int addAtHead(WordList **w_ptr, char *word) {
  WordList *head, *w;
  w = *w_ptr;
  head = w;

  while (w != NULL && strcmp(w->word, word) != 0)
     w = w->next_word;

  if (w == NULL) {
     WordList *newstruct;
     newstruct = malloc(sizeof *newstruct);
     if(newstruct == NULL) /* out of memory etc. */
       return -1;
     size_t length = strlen(word) + 1;
     newstruct->word = malloc(length);
     if(newstruct->word == NULL){
       free(newstruct);
       return -2;
     }
     memcpy(newstruct->word, word, length);

     newstruct->occur = 0;
     newstruct->next_word = head;
     w = newstruct;
     printf("address: %p, head: %p\n", w, head);
     *w_ptr = newstruct;
  }
  return ++(w->occur);
}

void printWordList(WordList *w) {
  for ( ; w; w = w->next_word)
     printf("Word: %s\nOccurrences: %d\n\n",
        w->word, w->occur);
}

int main(void) {
  int rv = 0;    
  WordList *w = NULL;

  rv = addAtHead(&w, "world");
  printf("addAtHead = %d\n",rv);
  rv = addAtHead(&w, "hello");
  printf("addAtHead = %d\n",rv);
  if(w == NULL){
    printf("w == NULL\n");
  } else { 
    printf("pointer address: %p\n",w);  
  }
  printWordList(w);
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to change a pointer in the function and want to get this changed pointer back: Either you return a pointer (the function is build like `Wordlist * addAtHead(....)` or you can use (in our case) a pointer to that pointer. You have to get a reference to that pointer.